# How does my server pick which key it uses with an SSH client?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

In the `/etc/ssh/` directory there are three different keys:

- ECDSA Key
- RSA Key

and

- ED225519 Key

How does my server choose which one it will use during a connection? Generally when I connect to it I only see the ECDSA key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays OpenSSH uses ECDSA by default, but client side can request a specific key algorithm, for example:

```
ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms='ssh-rsa' server
```

or through a `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server
  HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa
```

---

On server-side you can enable or comment out the algorithms in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, for example:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
# HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
# HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```